# Sort the XML based on node value using <xsl:sort> and change the element name issue

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I tried to sort the XML based on the value for given xml. from request xml i need sort based on educational_details {DR,PDR,MSC,BSC}. I have use . please see the sample below.

input xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
       <document>
         <studentname>ACM</studentname>
         <educational_details>MSC</educational_details>
       </document>
       <document>
         <studentname>ACB</studentname>
         <educational_details>BSc</educational_details>
       </document>
       <document>
         <studentname>ACP</studentname>
         <educational_details>PDR</educational_details>
       </document>
       <document>
         <studentname>ACC</studentname>
         <educational_details>DR</educational_details>
       </document>
</root>
```

Transformation  XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:param name="pOrder" select="'DR,PDR,MSC,BSc'" />

        <xsl:variable name="vSequence" select="tokenize($pOrder, ',')"/>

        <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="root">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="document">
                    <xsl:sort
                        select="index-of($vSequence, educational_details)" />
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

lookup xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lookups>
    <lookup tc="13" responce="Doctor" request="DR" />   
    <lookup tc="12" responce="Post DR" request="PDR" />
    <lookup tc="30" responce="Master of Scienc" request="MSc" />    
    <lookup tc="4" responce="Bachelor of Science" request="BSc" />
</lookups>
```

output xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <root>
               <document>
                 <studentname>ACM</studentname>
                 <stu_educational_details tc="30">Master of Scienc</stu_educational_details>
               </document>
               <document>
                 <studentname>ACB</studentname>
                 <stu_educational_details tc="4">Bachelor of Science</stu_educational_details>
               </document>
               <document>
                 <studentname>ACP</studentname>
                 <stu_educational_details tc="12">Post DR</stu_educational_details>
               </document>
               <document>
                 <studentname>ACC</studentname>
                 <stu_educational_details tc="13">Doctor</stu_educational_details>
               </document>
        </root>
```

Expected output

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <root>
                  <document>
                     <studentname>ACC</studentname>
                     <stu_educational_details tc="13">Doctor</stu_educational_details>
                   </document>
                   <document>
                     <studentname>ACP</studentname>
                     <stu_educational_details tc="12">Post DR</stu_educational_details>
                   </document>
                   <document>
                     <studentname>ACM</studentname>
                     <stu_educational_details tc="30">Master of Scienc</stu_educational_details>
                   </document>
                   <document>
                     <studentname>ACB</studentname>
                     <stu_educational_details tc="4">Bachelor of Science</stu_educational_details>
                   </document>
              </root>
```

I wrote the logic to change the element and value name.

Comment: Your Inout file transformed with your stylesheet does not produce the exact structure of your output file. Can you show your actual XSLT? Transforming your Input file with your Stylesheet does deliver the correct order though... so either you are overiding the pOrder Parameter when you run your transformation, or there is another issue in your actual stylesheet.

Comment: I think the issue with overiding the pOrder Parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stylesheet you have posted is the one I suggested as a response to your earlier question, it would do the sorting, but it does not produce the renaming and replacement you want additionally.

The renaming is easy to add:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:param name="pOrder" select="'DR,PDR,MSC,BSc'" />

        <xsl:variable name="vSequence" select="tokenize($pOrder, ',')"/>

        <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="root">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="document">
                    <xsl:sort
                        select="index-of($vSequence, educational_details)" />
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="educational_details">
          <stu_educational_details>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </stu_educational_details>
        </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

As for adding the attribute and replacing the codes like `"DR"`, you will at least need to show us where the data like the `tc` numbers and the replacement strings like `"Doctor"` come from. Normally one would use a lookup document and simply use a key to find the values.

Here is an edit with a key used for the lookup:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

        <xsl:param name="lookup-url" select="'test2014053002.xml'"/>

        <xsl:variable name="lookup-doc" select="doc($lookup-url)"/>

        <xsl:param name="pOrder" select="'DR,PDR,MSC,BSc'" />

        <xsl:variable name="vSequence" select="tokenize($pOrder, ',')"/>

        <xsl:key name="codes" match="lookup" use="@request"/>

        <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="root">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="document">
                    <xsl:sort
                        select="index-of($vSequence, educational_details)" />
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="educational_details">
          <stu_educational_details tc="{key('codes', ., $lookup-doc)/@tc}">
            <xsl:value-of select="key('codes', ., $lookup-doc)/@responce"/>
          </stu_educational_details>
        </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that currently your samples use different spelling (`responce` instead of `response`) as usual and different case of letters in the `request` attribute values and some of the sample data, you might need to normalize the spelling or you need to add `<xsl:key name="codes" match="lookup" use="upper-case(@request)"/>` and e.g. `key('codes', upper-case(.), $lookup-doc)`.

Comment: correct. i have edit the question with the lookup xml. could you please check